# How will be determined the format of manuscript before submission to journal?

Tags: mathematics, paper-submission

I would like to submit my paper to a math journal. In the section of instructions for authors there is the following statement which I am confused of its meaning, may you please help me to sort out of that.

> The manuscript should be in final form; once "communicated'', little change will be allowed.

Does it mean that I must write my paper in the final format of journal  before submission?

Comment: I'd understand the quoted sentence as referring to the paper's content, not the format. (But check the rest of the instructions for anything about format.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the journal's typesetters will get your manuscript into that "final form", so you don't have to do it yourself.

The sentence is saying that you should have all your content finalized before submission. Once the paper is communicated, you can't make any more changes.